# Error in Discord.js message.author.timeout() is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I tried to run the following code:

```
message.author.timeout(10 * 60 * 1000)
```

However this resulted in an error stating its not a function:

```
message.author.timeout(10 * 60 * 1000)
```

Should be working since its referring to a guild member.

Comment: What are you referring to actually? A `cooldown` for every author using it?

Comment: No discords timeout function aka muting

Comment: Ah you wanted to mute a member?

Answer (score 2):

First, you should verify that you are using the latest version of the Discord.js library, which includes the [GuildMember#timeout()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=timeout) method.

The `GuildMember#timeout()` method takes two parameters: time (in milliseconds, required) and reason (optional).

What is wrong with the code is that the function is being applied to a **Discord User**, not a **Guild Member**. Methods that act directly with a guild member and require information such as roles, permissions and other things, must be applied to the Guild Member, an object that holds both Discord User and Guild data.

`message.author` is a Discord User.
`message.member` is a Guild Member.

So the code should be:

```
message.member.timeout(10 * 60 * 1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `GuildMember#timeout()` directed to the member **example**:

getting the member first:

```
const member = message.mentions.members.first() // This is where you tagging the member you wanted to mute
```

you can also use their ID's

```
const member = message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) //This is you can use their id's
```

Or add them both:

```
const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
```

To return the command if no member mentioned or id given

```
if(!member) return message.reply("Your Message")
```

after using this command lines you can now use the `GuildMember#timeout()`

```
member.timeout(10 * 6 * 1000) //This will be your `timeout 60 seconds`
```

you can also use a package called `ms`

```
const ms = require('ms')
let time = args[1]
member.timeout(time)
```

overall code:

```
const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
    let time = ms(args[1])

    if(!member) return message.reply("Your Message")
    if(!time) return message.reply("Your message")
    member.timeout(time)

    message.channel.send(member.user.username + " has been timed out")
```

using the `ms` you can give such as `ms/s/m/h/d`

```
ms = 1000 = 1s
s = 1s
m = 1m
h = 1h
d = 1d
```